# Do I need to declare queryset in both ViewSet and Serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm working to add a categories system to my app and wonder about something that has been bothering me for some time when creating `viewsets` and `serializers`.

#### ViewSet

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer
```

#### Serializer

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models = Category
        queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

#### Questions

- Do I need to declare `queryset`  in both ViewSet and Serializer in Django Rest Framework?
- When customizing a `queryset` is adding `get_queryset()` to my viewset the "right" way?

Comment: You only need your `queryset` in your view most, if not all, of the times. If you want to customise your `queryset` then you will have to override `get_queryset()` of your ModelViewSet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `View` needs the `queryset` to know what object set you are working on as well as for refining filtering and pagination.

The `Serializer` needs the model to extract the fields and automatically create/update the instance.